# I'm trying to change the color of the textfield of a touch UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, aem

The textfield has the id "colormeup". But this doesn't seem to be working.The event is not getting bound to the textfield.

The following is the js code in the clientlib.

```js
(function (document) {
        var $form = $(document).find("form.foundation-form");
        var $in = $form.find("#colormeup");
        $in.mouseenter(function(){
           $(this).css("border", "1px solid #861bc4");
        });
})(document);
```

```html
<form action="/content/validator/_jcr_content/Body/colorcheck" method="post" class="coral-Form coral-Text cq-dialog foundation-form content foundation-layout-form cq-dialog-floating coral-Form--aligned coral--dark" data-cq-dialog-pageeditor="/editor.html/content/validator.html" data-foundation-form-ajax="true" style="top: 11.25px; left: 402.5px;">

<div class="cq-dialog-content coral-TabPanel coral-TabPanel--large" data-init="tabs">
<nav class="coral-TabPanel-navigation" role="tablist">
<a class="coral-TabPanel-tab is-active" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="coral-84" aria-disabled="false">InfoValidator</a></nav>
 <div class="coral-TabPanel-content"><section class="coral-TabPanel-pane coral-FixedColumn foundation-layout-util-vmargin is-active" id="coral-84" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
<div class="coral-FixedColumn-column">
<div class="coral-Form-fieldwrapper">
<label class="coral-Form-fieldlabel">Email</label>
<input class="coral-Form-field coral-Textfield" id="colormeup" data-rootpath="/content/dam/barclays" type="text" name="./email" value="xxxxx@gmail.com" data-validation="">
<span class="coral-Form-fieldinfo coral-Icon coral-Icon--infoCircle coral-Icon--sizeS" data-init="quicktip" data-quicktip-type="info" data-quicktip-arrow="right" data-quicktip-content="Enter Email Id" aria-label="Enter Email Id" tabindex="0"></span></div></div>


</section>


</div></div>

</form>
```

Comment: `colormeup` is an ID but are you sure it is a unique ID in context?

Comment: You should console log $in object, for checking that are you really getting correct object or not

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you did not provide enough info. add the HTML code of the page to the question

Comment: I have tried using provided html and js code, and it is working as expected

Answer (score 1):

Try with `find` instead of `closest`.`closest` target with parent element, `document` not have parent .And one more thing you could define the range of the border in css or in js like `border:1px solid color` .Without mention the range `border-color` not visible

**Working example**

```js
(function(document) {
  var $form = $(document).find("form.foundation-form");
  var $in = $form.find("#colormeup");
  $in.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid #861bc4");
  });
})(document);
```

```css
#colormeup {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/content/validator/_jcr_content/Body/colorcheck" method="post" class="coral-Form coral-Text cq-dialog foundation-form content foundation-layout-form cq-dialog-floating coral-Form--aligned coral--dark" data-cq-dialog-pageeditor="/editor.html/content/validator.html"
  data-foundation-form-ajax="true" style="top: 11.25px; left: 402.5px;">

  <div class="cq-dialog-content coral-TabPanel coral-TabPanel--large" data-init="tabs">
    <nav class="coral-TabPanel-navigation" role="tablist">
      <a class="coral-TabPanel-tab is-active" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="coral-84" aria-disabled="false">InfoValidator</a></nav>
    <div class="coral-TabPanel-content">
      <section class="coral-TabPanel-pane coral-FixedColumn foundation-layout-util-vmargin is-active" id="coral-84" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="coral-FixedColumn-column">
          <div class="coral-Form-fieldwrapper">
            <label class="coral-Form-fieldlabel">Email</label>
            <input class="coral-Form-field coral-Textfield" id="colormeup" data-rootpath="/content/dam/barclays" type="text" name="./email" value="xxxxx@gmail.com" data-validation="">
            <span class="coral-Form-fieldinfo coral-Icon coral-Icon--infoCircle coral-Icon--sizeS" data-init="quicktip" data-quicktip-type="info" data-quicktip-arrow="right" data-quicktip-content="Enter Email Id" aria-label="Enter Email Id" tabindex="0"></span></div>
        </div>


      </section>


    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Or simply you can use with [`css hover`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwju773B1v3TAhUFro8KHSrUDKYQFggrMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcssref%2Fsel_hover.asp&usg=AFQjCNGsp1Az0roCisrFWpUXDrnokPp2qw)

```css
#colormeup{

}
#colormeup:hover{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form action="/content/validator/_jcr_content/Body/colorcheck" method="post" class="coral-Form coral-Text cq-dialog foundation-form content foundation-layout-form cq-dialog-floating coral-Form--aligned coral--dark" data-cq-dialog-pageeditor="/editor.html/content/validator.html"
  data-foundation-form-ajax="true" style="top: 11.25px; left: 402.5px;">

  <div class="cq-dialog-content coral-TabPanel coral-TabPanel--large" data-init="tabs">
    <nav class="coral-TabPanel-navigation" role="tablist">
      <a class="coral-TabPanel-tab is-active" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="coral-84" aria-disabled="false">InfoValidator</a></nav>
    <div class="coral-TabPanel-content">
      <section class="coral-TabPanel-pane coral-FixedColumn foundation-layout-util-vmargin is-active" id="coral-84" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="coral-FixedColumn-column">
          <div class="coral-Form-fieldwrapper">
            <label class="coral-Form-fieldlabel">Email</label>
            <input class="coral-Form-field coral-Textfield" id="colormeup" data-rootpath="/content/dam/barclays" type="text" name="./email" value="xxxxx@gmail.com" data-validation="">
            <span class="coral-Form-fieldinfo coral-Icon coral-Icon--infoCircle coral-Icon--sizeS" data-init="quicktip" data-quicktip-type="info" data-quicktip-arrow="right" data-quicktip-content="Enter Email Id" aria-label="Enter Email Id" tabindex="0"></span></div>
        </div>


      </section>


    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```